# Run Odoo Automated Actions Daily

Tags: action, odoo, erp, odoo-11

I am trying to run an Odoo Automated task that emails users if they have a task deadline that is overdue or within 8 hours time. I would like this task to run daily so that I can affectively remind them about it.

However, I have encountered a few errors so far:

- The 'Automated Actions' builder that Odoo provides in debug mode needs a trigger. Timed conditions only give a datetime picker, therefore I cannot set it to 'daily' etc.
- I have tried setting a 'Scheduled Action' to the automated action to run it, but it isn't running - probably because the trigger isn't being hit (since there is options for on creation, when updated and timed conditions).

I hope this makes sense. Please see the screenshots below for what I have so far.

Automated Task:

[image]

Scheduled Task:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should set number of calls to -1 this means unlimited calls

Comment: I have tried this, however, I don't think the task is running because the automated task is on a timed condition, meaning I can't just run it whenever I would like to - and the tasks wont be updated or anything for it to run.

Comment: UPDATE  - I have created an automated action that works now (it goes off the model 'on update' event), which is linked to the scheduled action that SHOULD update the task in a way that it triggers the automated action. Everything works if I set it as a 'contextual action' and run it when looking at a task. However, when it runs daily, it doesn't have context (I want it to update 200 + tasks). Any ideas?